# Expression must be a modifiable lvalue when mallocing

Tags: c, malloc

I understand this question has been asked before, but I can't quite narrow down what i've done wrong here

```
int* arr[2];
arr = (int (*)[2]) malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
```

why is visual studio telling me the expression must be a modifiable lvalue? I'm trying to create an array with a constant column size, since that will always be two, but the rows will vary.

Comment: Many problems here.  `arr` is an array, not a pointer.  The cast type `(int (*)[2])` doesn't match the target type.  The size argument to `malloc` seems to be wrong (but can't know for certain until it can be compared to a valid pointer declaration).

Comment: Do not cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C!

Comment: Arrays cannot be assigned to as a whole in C . You can only assign to elements of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arr` is an array of pointers. You cannot assign anything to it once it is initialized. Since you are trying to set its value to be the return value of a call to `malloc`, you probably want it be a pointer to an array. In that case, use:

```
int (*arr)[2];
```

Also, don't cast the return value of `malloc`. See [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Use

```
int (*arr)[2];
arr = malloc(sizeof(*arr) * size);
          // ^^^^^^^^^^^^ We are speculating this is what you need,
          //              not sizeof(int)
```

If you want `arr` to point to an array of `15 x 2` objects, you will need to use:

```
arr = malloc(sizeof(*arr) * 15);
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `*2` in the `malloc`? If not, why not?

Comment: Your malloc size is wrong. Suggest `malloc(size * sizeof(*arr))`

Comment: Can I ask how you would access elements of that? It seems like the OP wants each element to be length two arrays, eg. `int* a = arr[0];` Or is there a way to get it as an array?

Comment: @matt, Sure, they can do that. Since `arr[0]` is of type `int [2]` and decays to the pointer to the first element in the array, it's OK to use `int* a = arr[0];`.

Answer (score 0):

you have an array of pointers....  that array can't be used as a pointer itself, only the array entries are pointers.

you need a pointer to pointers,  `int **`,  unless you are wanting an array of ints, then you just `int* arr`

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider using a struct? Then the syntax is a little more straight forward.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct Two Two;
struct Two{
  int b[2];
};
int main(){
  int size = 100;
  Two* two = malloc(sizeof(Two)*size);
  return 0;
}
```